# Hibernate query being cached wrong

Tags: mysql, hibernate, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

The below query is in my AuthorizedVoter and gets fired first before i access my API. This returns 1 result.

```
    " from School s inner join fetch s.student ss where s.Key = :schoolKey and      " +
        "s.accountKey = :accountKey and ss.Key= :studentKey " +
        "and ss.country='INDIA'"
```

The API fires the below query, The result from this query is also 1 row

```
SELECT DISTINCT
s.key, ss.studentkey
FROM
school s
    INNER JOIN
student ss ON s.key = ss.reportingsessionkey
    AND (ss.country='INDIA')
WHERE
session0_.key = ?
```

If i evict the cache, the return is 4 rows, which is the actual correct value.
I am not using any second level cache, It seems to be a first level cache problem.
Please help me find a better fix than evicting the cache in the API. Also what is the actual reason.

To add more to this when I run the 2 queries as a part of integration test one after the another results are fine.
The first query is part of Spring security and the second part of the API which would get called after that, It seems that somehow the student details are stored in the persistence context and continue to be used in the API.

Please find the link to the code on gihub https://github.com/agandhinit/crazy-hibernate

Comment: Do you have any additional configuration for the first level cache? That's such an extrange behaviour if using Hibernate with its defaults.

Comment: No specific config for first level cache, just the defaults.

Comment: Updated the post with the github link please check

Comment: Your github project has no db properties nor initialization scripts on it. There's no db, so when I request `http://localhost:8080/api/one?oneKey=1`I get a null pointer. I created a new issue if you want to discuss it there further afield: https://github.com/agandhinit/crazy-hibernate/issues/1

Comment: I did have a look to it. Quite extrange behaviour. I think, as you access both repo methods from a single controller call, Spring is managing a single transaction for you, that's where the Hibernate first level cache acts and gives the same result for both. If you split both calls in two controller methods, you'll see the issue won't happen, even if calling them from the same test method. How to solve it? I don't know, I've tried to use a service with transactional annotations, but seems to have the same problem.

Comment: I have the same issue